# Maui app hangs on splash screen when in release mode

Tags: android, maui

I have a Maui app that runs perfectly in debug mode but as soon as I change it to release and either run it on the Android emulator or device it hangs at the splash screen.

Comment: Am facing this issue even in Debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

After days of searching it turned out to be due to ZIndex being set in the xaml. I removed it from the xaml, gave the elements an x:Name and then set the ZIndex property in the code behind and it now works perfectly.

XAML: `<Grid x:Name="MyGrid"`

C#: `MyGrid.ZIndex = 2;`

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.
The exception was cryptic.

Enabling "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" under "Exception Settings" window provided more details (the actual exception indeed) and I discovered the issue was on a ZIndex.

Comment: Try to add examples that shows what you did to resolve the issue.